# Absolute ES6 import paths in configureless project?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, create-react-app

I want to use absolute imports like

```
import Button from 'components/iu/Button';
```

rather than

```
import Button from '../../../iu/Button';
```

The application has been created using create-react-app. The app currently has no `webpack.config.js` or `.babelrc`. I am uncertain to what extent I can create these files and add configuration and to what extent the create-react-app piping handles all of that out of sight.

How can I add absolute imports to the project?

Comment: eject your CRA then you will have a webpack config file to change.

Comment: @PlayMa256: Can I do it without ejecting?

Comment: no, you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider ejecting

Comment: Using absolute paths is generally considered a mistake. If `components` is truly something that isn't associated with one specific location, then it would likely make the most sense to have it actually be its own `node_modules`, in which case you'd get this behavior automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create file called `.env` in your root directory (where is `src` folder).

Put this line into `.env` file.

> NODE_PATH=src

Now you can use absolute import like `import Button from 'components/iu/Button';`.

Tested on **react-create-app 1.x**.

Answer (score 1):

@JaLe is right, and as he said, it seems this only works with create-react-app.

In addition, you should also add the following file to your project so that your IDE can give you correct module path autocompletions:

**jsconfig.json**

```
// Set up compilerOptions for VSCode, including how to resolve import statements (needed in accordance with the setup done in ".env")
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```